# JAVASCRIPT - Read local file, filter for a word and print word's line

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.  It can open a file and display it in the browser.  But I want to:
  - Select many files instead of one;
  - Then Filter on these files for a word (username);
  - Then print username's line (text file: username xxxx);
  - If the word "username" is not found  , print - text file: not found

Any idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Read File (via User Input selection)</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var reader; //GLOBAL File Reader object for demo purpose only

    /**
     * Check for the various File API support.
     */
    function checkFileAPI() {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            return true; 
        } else {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported by your browser. Fallback required.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * read text input
     */
    function readText(filePath) {
        var output = ""; //placeholder for text output
        if(filePath.files && filePath.files[0]) {           
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                output = e.target.result;
                displayContents(output);
            };//end onload()
            reader.readAsText(filePath.files[0]);
        }//end if html5 filelist support
        else if(ActiveXObject && filePath) { //fallback to IE 6-8 support via ActiveX
            try {
                reader = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                var file = reader.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1); //ActiveX File Object
                output = file.ReadAll(); //text contents of file
                file.Close(); //close file "input stream"
                displayContents(output);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.number == -2146827859) {
                    alert('Unable to access local files due to browser security settings. ' + 
                     'To overcome this, go to Tools->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level. ' + 
                     'Find the setting for "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe" and change it to "Enable" or "Prompt"'); 
                }
            }       
        }
        else { //this is where you could fallback to Java Applet, Flash or similar
            return false;
        }       
        return true;
    }   

    /**
     * display content using a basic HTML replacement
     */
    function displayContents(txt) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main'); 
        el.innerHTML = txt; //display output in DOM
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkFileAPI();">
    <div id="container">    
        <input type="file" onchange='readText(this)' />
        <br/>
        <hr/>   
        <h3>Contents of the Text file:</h3>
        <div id="main">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this, but does the basic idea work? Read the files through a for-loop, and search for your target string. If you get to the end and you dont find it, return your empty message;

```
function SearchFiles(var target_string, var file_paths){
    var fs = require("fs");

    my_file_paths.foreach(function(filepath){
        var text = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
        var pos = text.search(target_string);
        if (pos>1) {
            return text.substring(pos, pos + target_string.length);
        }
    }
    return "not found"
 }

// now to use the function
var my_file_paths; // init this to what you want to search through
var target_username; // init this as well
var found_username = SearchFiles(target_username, my_file_paths);

DisplayContents("text file: " + found_username);
```

Comment: Yes.  I tried with your code, but it is not displaying anything

Comment: There is no error log. Just does display anything.  I set the code as below:
    Added the code you sent under <script> tags and then:
<body>
    <div id="container">    
        <input type="file" onchange='SearchFiles()' />
        <br/>
        <hr/>   
        <h3>Contents of the Text file:</h3>